# How could I look for, and change, a variable in a firmware update (audio hardware)?

Tags: firmware

I have a TV-speaker system ( http://www.philips.co.uk/c-p/HTL5140B_12/soundbar-speaker ) which has downloadable software updates.

One of the software functions controls a 15-minute idle timer which puts the system in to standby mode when no audio input is received. This is a real pain in the ass as it means if you pause the TV for 15 minutes for any reason, you have to go and switch the unit back on. I'd like to change this value to 60 minutes.

The update found here http://www.philips.co.uk/c-p/HTL5140B_12/soundbar-speaker/support is a 2.5mb .bin file.

Although I have coding experience in Xcode, Unity and various other regular environments, I have no knowledge of decompiling and editing a file like this, or anything vaguely hack-y.

I guess the answer to this is not trivial, but hope I can get some tips on what I should be studying, googling, or what software would be a good start in exploring the file to look for clues.

Thanks

Steve

(BTW, I know this variable is used in the update as it has been changed from 30 to 15 at one time)

Answer (score 1):

It's more or less impossible, you'd have to reverse engineer the entire update and compile it again yourself after you "fix" the problem. Decompilers exist, but for the most part they decompile to machine code, which you could maybe find a solution with if you're a masochist.

There are a few decompilers that (poorly) write the source code out in C, but they're completely useless on larger files in my experience.

Comment: Thanks. It sounds like it's not worthwhile, but wanted to get some opinion anyway. Looks like a walk across the lounge is a better solution.